# Get Weather Info with API for android

Tags: android, networking, gps, location, weather

I want to get weather info using google weather api when I have longitude and latitude coordinates.So I take the codes:

```
private void updateWeather(){
    new Thread(){
        public void run() {
            //get Weather start:
              LocationHelper helper = new LocationHelper(MomentsActivity.this);
              Location location = helper.getLocation();

              if(null != location){
                  String request = "http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=,,,"+location.getLatitude()
                          +","+location.getLongitude();
                  XmlParserUtil parser = new XmlParserUtil(mHandler);
                  try {
                      parser.parse(HttpUtil.getWeather(request));
                  } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                  } catch (IOException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                  } catch (Exception e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                  }
              }
            //end
        };
    }.start();
}
```

But when I would like to get longitude and latitude from LocationManager,I found that the location was null all the time.Please see the codes for getting location:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;

public class LocationHelper {
    Context context;
    public LocationHelper(){}
    public LocationHelper(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }
    public Location getLocation(){
        LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location location = manager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if(null == location){
            location = manager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        }
        return location;
    }
}
```

Please help me find the bug.Thank you.

In addtion:
I added some permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" ></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" ></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" ></uses-permission>
```

All the same,I turned on the GPS and wifi,but the location was also null.

Comment: Have you added required permissions in manifiest file? see [Link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html).

Comment: I added some permissions:

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" ></uses-permission> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" ></uses-permission> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" ></uses-permission>

Answer (score 0):

```
     LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
                System.out.println("Location is: :" + location.toString());

            }

            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
        };

        // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
//      locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

You can get a lot fancier than this.  For example, runing the location code continuously is supposed to be a big battery drain.  You also need to listen to the multiple responses and filter to prioritize between accuracy and recentness.  Good luck.